# wrong results with VBA dictionnary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I'm new in VBA and I’m getting wrong results by doing a dictionary in VBA.

**Input :**

- column B : societies's ID
- column A : their stores'IDs
- column C : amounts

[image]

**Output expected:**

- Column E: societies ID
- Column F : stores ID (unique values)
- Column G : total amount of each stores ID

[image]

**What I get :**

[image]

Example: For the store ID FRPAN3 I’m supposed to have 351,48.

**Code :**

```
Option Explicit 
Dim dico As Object, f As Worksheet, i&

Sub ValeursUniques()

Set dico = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set f = Sheets("Feuil1")

For i = 2 To f.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    dico(f.Range("B" & i).Value) = dico(f.Range("B" & i).Value) + Val(f.Range("C" & i))
Next i

Range("F2").Resize(dico.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dico.keys)
Range("G2").Resize(dico.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dico.items)
End Sub
```

Any idea why I get those results ?

Comment: Can you show the output rather than use images.

Comment: Before summing up values in the dictionary, you need first to `Add` the new key with a starting value. Then you can sum up. Check how Dictionaries work [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Comment: Yes, you don't add anything to the dictionary.  You need to use `.add` to add and `.exists` to check for a keys presence.  Have a look at the help for the dictionary.

Comment: "FRPAIA I’m supposed to have 321,7" - I can't see how this relates to your data, and I can't see how your output relates to your input.

Comment: You don't need to use `Add`. `dico(f.Range("B" & i).Value)` automatically adds the item.

Comment: Adding decimals to the returned values, what does it happen? Will it add `00`, or there are hidden decimals?

Comment: You add the values of column F using `+ Val(f.Range("F" & i))` but the amounts you show in your screenshot are in column C? Can you clarify that? • Otherwise add a screenshot that show column F as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Val function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) may not return the correct value. If your values in column F `Val(f.Range("F" & i))` are actually non-integers their decimals can get cut off!

The documentation says

> *The Val function stops reading the string at the first character that it can't recognize as part of a number.*

> *The Val function recognizes only the period ( . ) as a valid decimal separator. When different decimal separators are used, as in international applications, use CDbl instead to convert a string to a number.*

So if there is any character in your number it will cut off. In your case the `,` counts as a character and therefore your values are turned into integers as the `,` is not treated as a decimal seperator.

Make sure to use [Type conversion functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) instead:

```
cDbl(f.Range("F" & i))
```

will convert the value into a floating point with double precision.

Comment: From the docs.... "The Val function recognizes only the period ( . ) as a valid decimal separator. When different decimal separators are used, as in international applications, use CDbl instead to convert a string to a number." I'm not sure if applicable or not, can't tell what numbers OP is actually summing

Comment: If this would be the problem, the value will be trunked, not rounded up and the total amount per dictionary key should be smaller, but **it is larger**...

Comment: @FaneDuru True unless there is something odd in the data like `"2 45 7"` which `Val` turns into `2457`. Nevertheless `Val` is a bad choice in any case.

Comment: By using cDb1, I get good results ! Thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

### Uniquify Data by Using a Dictionary

- If a value in the first Unique column (in this case column `2`) is an error value or a blank,
  the record will not be included.
- If a value in the other Unique columns (in this case only column `1`) is an error value,
  it will be converted to `Empty` (implicitly).
- If a value in the Value column (in this case column `3`) is not a number,
  `0` (zero) will be used instead.
- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UniquifyData()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Feuil1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Dim uCols As Variant: uCols = VBA.Array(2, 1)
    Const svCol As Long = 3
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Feuil1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "E1"
    ' Both
    Const Delimiter As String = "@"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range and write its values to the source array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress).CurrentRegion
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    ' Write the headers from the source array to the headers array.
    
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(uCols)
    Dim Headers As Variant: ReDim Headers(1 To cUpper + 2)
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 0 To cUpper
        Headers(c + 1) = Data(1, uCols(c))
    Next c
    Headers(cCount) = Data(1, svCol)
    
    ' Write the unique values from the source array to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim sString As String
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        For c = 0 To cUpper
            Key = Data(r, uCols(c))
            If c = 0 Then
                If Not IsError(Key) Then
                    If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                        sString = CStr(Key)
                    End If
                End If
                If Len(sString) = 0 Then Exit For
            Else
                If IsError(Key) Then Key = ""
                sString = sString & Delimiter & CStr(Key) ' join uniques
            End If
        Next c
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(Data(r, svCol)) Then
                dict(sString) = dict(sString) + Data(r, svCol)
            Else
                If Not dict.Exists(sString) Then dict(sString) = 0
            End If
            sString = ""
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dict.Count + 1
    
    ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Write the headers from the headers array to the destination array.
    
    For c = 1 To cCount
        Data(1, c) = Headers(c)
    Next c
    
    ' Write the values from the dictionary to the destination array.
    
    r = 1
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        r = r + 1
        ' Write uniques.
        uCols = Split(Key, Delimiter) ' split uniques
        For c = 0 To cUpper
            Data(r, c + 1) = uCols(c)
        Next
        ' Write value.
        Data(r, cCount) = dict(Key)
    Next Key
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, cCount) ' reference first row
        ' Write data.
        .Resize(drCount).Value = Data
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear
        ' Apply some formatting.
        '.Font.Bold = True ' headers
        '.EntireColumn.AutoFit ' columns
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
     
    MsgBox "Data uniquified.", vbInformation

End Sub
```